# grep a word/number between two specific characters

Tags: command-line, grep, sed, awk

When you ping you will get the ip between () , for e.g : (10.10.10.10)
and after the ip there are (number) for e.g : (10.10.10.10) 56(84)

so how i can get the ip that is between the ()  ? and without the second number ?

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you want to resolve a domain name, use `nslookup` or `host` or `dig`.

Comment: i just want the ip

Comment: when you ping you get other info
but i want to grep the ip only without anything else

Comment: thnx for suggestion but in my case i need to use ping
if you can help with grep it as i asked above i will be thankfull 
if you can't thank you  again sir

Comment: thnx for the link , it given my some help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will print the IP addresses only:

```bsh
ping -c1 askubuntu.com | grep -Eo '([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+'
```

But if you want to resolve a hostname, it would be better to use some other tool, e.g. `host`, `dig` `nslookup` or alike:

```bsh
dig +short askubuntu.com
# or
nslookup askubuntu.com | grep -Po "Address: \K.*"
```

See more solutions [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20784/how-can-i-resolve-a-hostname-to-an-ip-address-in-a-bash-script).